# How to resize the video in HTML5 dynamically?

Tags: html, html5-video

we have the requirement in the project that having 3 videos in an html page like shown in the following image.

[image]

Now by clicking at the bottom-right corner on each of this video user can resize the video and accordingly the size of other videos will change. The problem i am facing here is how to resize the video by just pressing and dragging the mouse click on the bottom-right corner of each video, i've tried using `resize` property of `video` tag but it resizes the width and height of the controllers of the video. Do i have to use any third party API or JavaScript or am i doing any silly mistake?

by doing some RND on this i came to know about `canvas`. but doesn't get any idea how to use it with video together.

can anyone please guide me here? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

**CODE :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
   video{
     resize:both;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">      
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is the code that i've used from w3school. but it resizes only the controllers not the entire video.

Comment: do not use w3schools, it has many things wrong

Comment: It is quite easy if you use some lib like jQueryUI resizable.

Comment: Ok. but can you help me on this ? see my edit.

Comment: @dfsq sure will give a try.

Comment: Some pointers. Wrap your videos into resizable divs and set videos styles `{width: 100%; height: 100%}`. The trickiest part is making divs resize synchronously.

Comment: I'm working on the demo now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be honest it's a little bit confusing that you have so many resize handles. It also makes things pretty complicated.

This is what I came up so far, this should give you a good sense of the complete implementation:

```
var $cont = $('#container'),
    contWidth = $cont.width(),
    contHeight = $cont.height(),
    $one = $('#one'),
    $two = $('#two'),
    $ltop = $one.find('.ltop'),
    $lbot = $one.find('.lbot');

$ltop.resizable({
    handles: 'se',
    minWidth: '100',
    maxWidth: '400',
    resize: function() {
        var width = $(this).width(),
            height = $(this).height(),
            remSpaceH = contWidth - width,
            remSpaceV = contHeight - height;

        $one.width(width);
        $two.width(remSpaceH - ($two.outerWidth() - $two.width()));

        $lbot.height(remSpaceV - ($lbot.outerHeight() - $lbot.height()));
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/KuAsz/

Comment: What is this doing?  All I see are three pictures, no resizing happening anywhere

Answer (score 2):

This is way better: http://jsfiddle.net/ScDmp/9/

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls id="myVideo">
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    <div>
        <input type="range" min="100" max="500" step="50" id="mySlider" value="0" onchange="document.getElementById('myVideo').width = this.value;"/>
```

Then you may change the input slider with a timer which will check the width of the canvas every second and re size the videos accordingly.

You may try something like this with jquery ui resizable:

```
function ready(){
    $("#myContainer").resizable();
    var interval = setInterval(checkWidth, 1000);

    function checkWidth()
    {
         $("#myVideo").width($("#myContainer").width());
    }
    setTimeout($("#myContainer").width("100px"),1000);

    setTimeout($("#myContainer").width("200px"),5000);

    setTimeout($("#myContainer").width("300px"),10000);
}
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want to use any extra controls like range, i want to resize it by dragging the bottom-right corner of the video only. and i think i have got the solution for that by using __jQueryUI resizable.__

Comment: @KunalK check my edit, I did this to show you that you may change the video width easy, will provide a more detailed example soon