# PHP - Change videoMediaMetadata Width and Height (Resolution) on Google Drive Video

Tags: php, video, google-api, google-drive-api, video-streaming

I already make API for get->files then accesss download url with token.
Everything is fine and work in jwplayer

My Json request :

```
 "videoMediaMetadata": {
 "width": 1280,
"height": 720,
 "durationMillis": "6330456"
 },
```

jwplayer source video example :

> https://doc-0s-1s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/qjrgdcogjm0ajgdp4fnjceh8pfg486sg/o021ctnh9hct13gf50dtv3v32io3qhkk/1473271200000/02390580194345273532/02390580194345273532/0B9LPSEw89uQNVlo3bnhTV1czV0E?e=download&gd=true

Then it's work when I click play,

The answer is, how to change width and height when I request API google or something to changes that resolution

example 720x480,

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the videoMediaMetadata width and height through API is not possible. You'd get an error like when you try to use [files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update)

```
"reason": "fieldNotWritable",
"message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
```

Editing videos' internal properties is more of a video editing software's task than it is with Google's APIs. If it's resizing videos on a browser, you can resort to [HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698961/how-to-resize-the-video-in-html5-dynamically).

Comment: Hmm, but google player have quality switch on their player, example myVideo.mp4 is 720p, then google player automatically had 3 option quality. even myVideo is only one. what do you think about that?