# Javascript video PIP mode

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using `requestPictureInPicture` to popup the html video element but the problem is size is limited to around 920 x 540 on PIP mode.

Is it possible to get larger size? OR except `requestPictureInPicture` is there any other library to get this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the limitation is 960*540 on screens with resolutions of 1920x1080. Smaller values may be related to the aspect ration of the video itself.

The limitation comes from the specification used for [this feature](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5729206566649856) and it's just a [recommendation](https://w3c.github.io/picture-in-picture/#request-pip). But most browsers make use of it:

> It is also RECOMMENDED that the Picture-in-Picture window has a maximum and minimum size. For example, it could be restricted to be between a quarter and a half of one dimension of the screen.

If you really need larger views than 50% of the current screen, you are able to make use of popup windows and play the video in there or use the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API). A challenge with the popup method is that the windows won't have a `always on top`-flag and/or option to activate it.

Another method would be to make the video element drag- and resizable. This would be similar to many instant messenger video players.

- [How to resize the video in HTML5 dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699932/10304804).
- Give the video (or it's container) element a `position: fixed;` and [add a small script for the user to move it around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45831670/10304804).